# Basics of Infinitary Formal Languages

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

Reading through Hodges' "A Shorter Model Theory", he gives the following symbolism (pgs. 23-25) for the first-order language constructed in the normal way with only finitely many formulas conjoined/disjoined together and only finitely many quantifiers in a row: $L_{\omega \omega}$.  The first subscript is, from what I can gather, meant as a strict upperbound for conjunction/disjunction, while the second is meant as a strict upperbound on quantification (I know that doesn't quite make sense--hence the question).  The notation is also meant to generalize in the obvious way to $L_{\alpha \beta}$.

Why is Hodges using the ordinal $\omega$ rather than, say, the cardinal $\aleph_0$?  Is the ordering he has in mind simply from left to right?  If so, how can this be meaningful given that, for example, his disjunction/conjunction operations are over sets of formulas (and thus seem to be without an ordering)?

Comment: For many of us cardinals *are* initial ordinals, and $\omega_\xi$ (and simply $\omega$ if $\xi=0$) is the normal notation for both the ordinal and the cardinal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the only reasons for writing $\omega$ rather than $\aleph_0$ in this context are (1) tradition and (2) avoiding second-level subscripts (for a while).  In particular, if conjunctions, disjunctions, and quantifier blocks are given as sets rather than sequences, then the $\omega$ here and the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in similar contexts should be understood as strict upper bounds for cardinalities.  No orderings should be involved.